# Strange LINQ Behaviour

Tags: c#, linq

I am stumped... I am probably doing something really stupid but just cannot see it...

I have a list of Inventory:

```
var scInventory = new List<SellerCloudInventory>();
```

I populate it:

```
scInventory = scInventoryEngine.GetInventory(_config["SellerCloud_FTPInventoryFile"], _config["PST_FTPUsername"], _config["PST_FTPPassword"]);
```

I then want to pull out a particular product based on it's ProductId:

```
var scProduct = scInventory.Where(x => x.ProductID == lineitem.ProductID).FirstOrDefault();
```

lineitem.ProductID has a value of "PST-47-150-1532" and i have even tried hard coding this to replace lineitem.ProductID but same error....

When i try to do a "Quick Watch" the error "'scProduct' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'" is thrown.

But. When i run "scInventory.Where(x => x.ProductID == lineitem.ProductID).FirstOrDefault();" in the Immediate Pane it comes back with a product as expected.

I'm stumped... why would it work correctly in the immediate pane and not in the code?

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you maybe dump the json representation of `scInventory` and `lineitem` to a file? That always helps me, then you can copy and paste and compare freely, without your IDE or connections or timeouts getting in your way. I know the IDE *should* be super helpful, but sometimes, it's not.

Comment: Then your call to `GetInventory` doesn't return an item with the `"PST-47-150-1532"` ID.

Comment: Also, you're not ***populating*** the list, you're ***replacing*** it.

Comment: Also you can put your where clause inside your FirstOrDefault i.e. `scInventory.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ProductID == lineitem.ProductID)`